# How to set service worker with webpack encore?

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, service-worker, webpack-encore

About everything is in the title, I would like to know how to set my service worker with Webpack Encore.

I tried to use `.addEntry('sw', './assets/js/sw.js')` inside `webpack.config.js`, but,
while `navigator.serviceWorker.register("/build/sw.js")` is working in dev env,
the compiled file in prod is renamed `/build/sw.8346cedc.js`, which doesn't match the call anymore.

What should I do to be able to call my service worker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain service worker script path using `{{ encore_entry_js_files('sw') }}` twig function.

Create a global variable in html like following snipped.

```
<script>
var swPath = "{{ encore_entry_js_files('sw') | first }}";
</script>
```

You can still get trouble if your webpack.config.js has `.splitEntryChunks()` function because runtime.js is going to be seperated.

Comment: Ah, so the `.splitEntryChunks()` was my problem... Thanks, that was helpful